# Ember: how to get coverage on the actual code, not the transpiled code

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, continuous-integration, code-climate, karma-qunit

I'm trying to set up CI on existing projects, some use CoffeeScript, some use ES6 syntax. But I can't find a way to get a proper code coverage on the actual code. All I have is the coverage on the transpiled code and it seems I can't even post that to CodeClimate.

I tried:

- [ember-cli-blanket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-blanket): found on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494839/ember-cli-code-coverage-reports). It gives result on the transpiled sources only:

  > In fact, there is current no direct mapping between the es6 module names in the lcov output and the original input files.
- [ember-cli-code-coverage](https://github.com/kategengler/ember-cli-code-coverage): simpler but still run on the transpiled sources
- [karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/emberjs.html): (the link goes to a tutorial for Ember & karma) here PhantomJS complaints about ES6 syntax "import" (which is normal).

  - I tried to use a pre-processor to transpile the code.
  - There are a lot of possible things to do with browserify, webpack, etc... but I didn't figure out how to set up anything correctly.
  - I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/yesley/130962ae57ee5bc0f680) that could be interesting because it combines karma, browserify, babelify, Istanbul and PhantomJS, only qunit is missing. But I didn't succeeded to make anything work.